# Is it possible to simplify "a person born as an X"?

Tags: single-word-requests, sexual-minorities

The title is already clear, but I think I should give my reason why I ask this question. I found this word "woman-born" which means "a human who is born from a woman". Even though there was a special condition when it might not true such as a man carried a human inside him which is of course rare, isn't this word useless?

From Lexico:

> woman-born: noun. A person who is born from a woman; a human.

Back to my question, is there one word or at least a noun but not a noun-phrase to define a human born as a male or a human born as a female, which means, these words will always could define everyone with their original gender despite the fact that they will change their gender symbolically and physically in the future?

Comment: The idiom is used in a somewhat poetic sense to mean "human".

Comment: I don't think we have any single words that specify the gender at birth. It's only very recently that discussion of the varieties of gender have become mainstream, and terminology is still in flux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In online queer spaces, the terms "assigned (male/female) at birth" are often used. (Though not universally accepted.) While the full thing is a mouthful, the abbreviated versions AMAB and AFAB are common.

Why "assigned"? Because it dodges all the contentious issues in defining what, exactly, "birth sex" is supposed to mean.  Someone looked at a baby and assigned them a gender based on their outward appearance. And in the cases where it matters at all, this is generally what folk are talking about.

Another term you might sometimes see is "chromosomal sex".  But outside certain medical contexts, that is almost never really what's relevant.